# Exporting all equations from a document as individual svg files

Tags: equations, conversion, svg

I'm currently a presentation based on a paper originally written in Latex. Currently, I use Kile and Ubuntu for my work.

What I'm finding is that I need a large number of the equations from the original paper scattered around the presentations (and are using them to annotate diagrams etc).  My current method of screenshots + gimp is rather slow :)

So, what I would like to do is compile the tex document and instead of creating a pdf/dvi, I would like it to spit out a number of files, which each file being one of the equations from the document, preferably in a vector format, but I will live with a PNG if I have to, so long as it's of high enough resolution.

I've had a look at a number of utilities.

The following web utility: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php does more or less what I want for an individually typed equation. However, I've used a lot of mactros in equations that make it a little messy to use (for example)

```
\newcommand{\SkewSymmetric}[1]{\ensuremath{ \left[ #1 \right]_{\times}}}
```

I've had a look at pdf2svg, but it doesn't quite do what I want - I still need to crop out the equation of interest.

Is there anything else I should look at?

Comment: Are you not writing your presentation in LaTeX?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit it, but no :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out the [preview](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/preview.html) package.  E.g., including

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation}
```

prints all `equation` environments and nothing else, each cropped, one to a page.  It's equally effective with DVI and pdf output.  Embedded macros in `equation` (or whatever) environments are handled transparently and properly.

The pdf can then be converted to SVG images with the following command:

```
pdf2svg filename.pdf output-page%03d.svg all
```

Comment: the option `displaymath` should do it anyway.

Comment: Almost... The equation number is still embedded in each equation. Is there a way to automatically get rid of it?

Comment: @Damien: sure, assuming your document is based on one of the standard LaTeX classes, define the equation number out of existence thus: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\@eqnnum{}\makeatother`.

Comment: Not sure what I've done wrong. I've placed the suggested \makeatletter command before \begin{document} and after. It seems not to make a difference, even with a standard template. Any ideas?

Comment: I have included some additional notes in a new answer below to get rid of the whitespace and embedded equation numbering.

Comment: @Damien use `\makeatletter\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{}\makeatother` if using amsmath.

Comment: Link moved to https://ctan.org/pkg/preview?lang=en

Comment: Note that the code snippet in this answer must be placed after `\usepackage{mathtools}`

Answer (score 9):

To extend the answer from @Kilgore:

To get rid of the equation numbers (AND you have an excellent backup of the original file(s)!), yon can do the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

files=`find . | grep -e '\.tex$'`

for file in $files ; do 

    echo "Stripping: $file"

    # Create a copy of the existing file
    cp $file $file.strip_backup

    sed -i 's/begin{equation\*}/begin{align*}/g'   $file
    sed -i 's/end{equation\*}/end{align*}/g'   $file

    sed -i 's/begin{equation}/begin{align*}/g'   $file
    sed -i 's/end{equation}/end{align*}/g'   $file

    sed -i 's/begin{align}/begin{align*}/g'   $file
    sed -i 's/end{align}/end{align*}/g'   $file

done
```

The individual equations can be extracted using:

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{align*}
```

(Note the addition of the *)

To remove the excessive whitespace, use the following utility:

```bash
pdfcrop output.pdf
```

And, finally, you can split this into individual svg files

```bash
mkdir output-equations
pdf2svg filename.pdf output-equations/output-page%03d.svg all
```

If the svg images are still not properly cropped, Inkscape can fix that:

```bash
inkscape -z --verb=FitCanvasToDrawing --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose output-equations/*.svg
```

Comment: if you get `! LaTeX Error: Command \align* already defined.`, be sure to `\usepackage{mathtools}` *before* `preview`

Answer (score 1):

Make a Metapost file with one figure per equation, with each equation in an "unboxed box":

```
beginfig(1)
  boxit.a(btex $$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$ etex);
  a.c = (0,0);
  drawunboxed(a);
endfig(1);

beginfig(2)
  boxit.a(btex $$F={G m_1 m_2 \over d^2}$$ etex);
  a.c = (0,0);
  drawunboxed(a);
endfig(2);
```

Run `mptosvg`, which will generate one SVG file per figure, with the right bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        1-\strut\displaystyle\frac{2\,M}{r}, \quad \text{for}\, r>R,
    \end{equation}

    foo $ xy=f(x) $ bar

    foo \[ dy=g(x) \] bar
\end{document}
```

**Latex to SVG** cmd

```
$latex test.tex
$dvisvgm.exe -n -p 1-5 -c 1.2,1.2 test.dvi
```

Comment: Have you tested this with a document with multiple `equation` environments to see that it does what the OP calls for? (And please format code blocks properly so others can easily cut and paste.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you anyway for sharing your knowledge! To format code, you can [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ltximg](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltximg) package, which uses the `preview` package internally but also crops the generated fragments and converts them to many different formats. You could use @Damien's answer above to convert all math environments into `align*`'s and call:

```
ltximg --latex --extrenv 'align*' --imgdir eqs --svg --png -o test-out test_eq.tex
```

to get pdf, svg and png fragments extracted from `test_eq.tex` into `eqs` directory. ltximg by default extracts only picture environments (tikz, pstricks, etc.), so we need to use `--extrenv` to specify math environments.