# LaTeX: outputting a "tight" svg

Tags: svg

## Concise Problem Statement

Given an input of a *.tex (LaTeX) file, I want to output a "tight" *.svg file.
By "tight", I mean a svg file that does not show the full page -- rather, just the rendered TeX file with a minimal border around it.

## Context

I have some LaTeX math equations that I would like to convert into svg. I do not want the svg files to be full 8.5x11 pages. I want my svg files to be the size of the bounding box of my math equations.

I would prefer a full automated, command line solution (i.e. no interactive editing in an external program.)

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  You should have a look at [the `standalone` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) as that might be what you are after.  See for example [Crop entire document around figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32583/crop-entire-document-around-figure).

Comment: @Peter: The standalone package looks like half of what I need. How do I output svg?

Comment: For convertion, see [Convert PDF to SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4120567/914686). [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) as a GUI and command-line tool is the way to go. There are other means also.

Comment: You can convert PDF to SVG as per [Exporting all equations from a document as individual svg files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/exporting-all-equations-from-a-document-as-individual-svg-files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [dvisvgm](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/) does exactly what you're looking for. It converts DVI files to SVG with tight bounding boxes. The tool is also part of TeX Live 2010 and above.

Comment: dvisvgm + standalone did the trick. Thanks!