# Disable numbering of equations globally in preamble without switching to starred math environments

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I would like to disable the numbering of all equations in my latex document without changing math environments to their starred version.

The scenario is: I have a long document and I would like to produce one pdf where equations are numbered and another one where they aren't.
So my idea was to simply trigger the desired behavior by adding appropriate commands in the preamble.

I tried `\makeatletter\renewcommand\@eqnnum{}\makeatother` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14977/63717), but this does not seem to do anything.

I use `align`, `alignat` and `equation` environments.
Thank you.

Comment: What should happen to cross references?

Comment: oh yes should have mentioned. I want to additionally extract the equations via the `preview` package so It does not matter that cross sections do not function any more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `amsmath` package. If that's the case, all you need to do is to issue the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{}
\makeatother
```